# How to set permissions on a wijmo menu?

Tags: jquery, menuitem, wijmo

I just downloaded the Wijmo open for Juice UI and I tried the wijmenu. It was very easy to use.

The problem is that I need to set permissions on the menu item level.
How do I dynamically do that or where can I set the role and disable a menu item based on that role. I'm new to JQuery so please bear with me.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Permissions should go server side. On the client side it doesn't make sense as it can always be overriden by the user.

Answer (score 0):

d_inevitable has the correct answer--you should perform security trimming on the server side.  If you need additional help with this, our support team monitors the product forums; the jUCIE UI forum is at http://our.componentone.com/groups/asp-net/wijmo-open-juice-ui/forum/.